# Install ANT (and JAVA) on server

Tags: java, android, linux, ant

I am trying to install ANT (to build/compile Android apps) on a local Linux (Ubuntu) installation so that I can install it on a live server (work out the kinks first).

The following is a set of commands I have run to get to where I am:

```
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/ant-current-src.zip /dest/folder
unzip ant-current-src.zip
wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u25-b06/jdk-6u25-linux-x64.bin /dest/folder
./jdk-6u25-linux-x64.bin 
(backup PATH :P ) 

export JAVA_HOME=jdk1.6.0_25 export
PATH=$PATH:jdk1.6.0_25/bin 

wget http://voxel.dl.sourceforge.net/project/junit/junit/4.10/junit-4.10.jar
cp junit-4.10.jar junit.jar
rm junit-4.10.jar
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JUNIT_HOME
```

With the following screenshot showing the output of the terminal:
[image]
At this point I'm stumped...

### RESOURCES:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html -> Installing Apache Ant -> Building Ant

Comment: I believe it's sufficient to symlink the contents of `bin` into `/usr/local/bin`. Also, this might be better on SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: For Ubuntu, couldn't you just install it from the repos? `sudo apt-get install ant`

Comment: Please cut-and-paste text instead of using a screenshot.

Comment: Use the Ant binary distro; there's zero reason to build it. Download, unzip, add its `bin` directory to your path. I'm against using package installers to install most Java software--just unzip it into a version-specific directory and set your path. This allows you to have explicit control over what version you're running, where it's installed, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to build ant to use and you can just install Java and Ant from the ubuntu packages.

> sudo apt-get install ant

should install Java and ant for you.

Comment: In general, on any OS that has a package management system: You *may* be able to build anything you want to, from sources, install in `/opt` or `/usr/local`, and do some nice things with it: but the gains for doing so are *almost always* extremely marginal. Letting the OS's package manager (`pkcon`,`apt`,`yum`) do the work for you means you get OS-specific patches, automatic bug fixes, and painless installations and removals. About the only exception is to build alpha software or something not in your OS's repositories…

Comment: @BRPocock - reply with that as an answer and i'll accept it as the answer - its the only way I could get it to work

Comment: @Manfred Moser hit the answer, I was just expanding upon the *why* :-)